# gazebo standalne version cannot be started as usual after installing gazebo ros packages

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello

I have installed gazebo 1.9 and gazebo_ros_pkgs successfully following the instructions in the tutorials both installed from source and I am running ros groovy. And I tested gazebo using this command :
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo , and it run successfully as well.
But the problem is when I want  to run gazebo standalone with my world file  as usual without ros integration as following  “gazebo file.world “

Even though there is no other gazebo running I get this error :Exception [Master.cc:50] Unable to start server[Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.

Any solutions for this error!
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4142/gazebo-standalne-version-cannot-be-started-as-usual-after-installing-gazebo-ros-packages/) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Did you try?

```
killall gzserver
```

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-08-12**:
I just did, and it works. thanks a lot!

**Comment by [_sparkle_eyes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11820/_sparkle_eyes/) on 2019-05-30**:
For some reason this is not working for me?